# Microsoft Project installation manual?

Tags: microsoft-project

Does anyone know where I can find a good installation manual for Microsoft project? I have a client looking for this product.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific person or are you just looking for an installation guide?  If you are looking for people, this would not the website to facilitate that.  I edited your question to look for an installation guide instead.

Comment: Just run the installer and take the default options. It's what works for me. Unless you're after a "non-standard" copy of course.

Comment: What version of Project?  And is it Project or project Server?